# Is it possible to make auto page numbering for Adobe Illustrator artboards?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am using 'Adobe Illustrator' for designing inner pages for books. In Indesign I was able to make the page numbers auto-generated. Is there any similar or any way to the same task on Illustrator?

(I am using Adobe Illustrator CS6)

Comment: There is a script for this, it works in CS4 and later.  https://aiscripts.com/insert-page-numbers-v2/ - I have no link with the developer or the website

Comment: Just a tip: Don't use Illustrator to design books, use InDesign. When you start to need scripts to perform simple tasks you're probably in the wrong application.